# Can I safely drill into a wall behind which is my fireplace and chimney?

Tags: drill, fireplace, hanging, chimney

I would like to drill 2-4 holes to mount a monitor on the wall of my office. The problem is that on the other side of my plaster wall is the back of my fireplace and chimney. Can I safely drill into my wall without compromising the integrity of either of these things?

Comment: Is the wall drywall on the office side?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't know how that part of the wall is framed.  Are there any vertical 2x4's behind the plaster.  Typical construction for a plaster wall (depending on the age of the house) is 2x4, lathe, screed (?) undercoat, then the final plaster coat.

Comment: What are the chimney/fireplace made out of? Are they _inside_ the wall, or on the other side?

Comment: A picture of the wall you're drilling into, the other side of said wall, and a pic of the doorway (with a tape measure to show us how thick said wall is) will go a long way toward helping to determine an answer. You may, though, just need to start by drilling a pilot hole where one of the mounting bolts is going to go to see what you hit...

Comment: Additionally, are the fireplace & chimney in use? Is the chimney lined or just brick/block?

Comment: Is there a natural gas pipe going into the fireplace?

Comment: What are the walls made of? Most North American single-family houses use a wooden frame, with lath & plaster (old style) or drywall (new style) over that. But that's not a universal rule, and I don't even know where you are.

Comment: Have you tried using a studfinder -- or a magnet -- to establish where the studs are yet? You are probably going to want to affix your mount to studs anyway, for strength, and if studs exist then drilling into them should be safe (assuming you aren't drilling entirely unreasonably deep. If there are no studs behind the plaster -- if it's right over the chimney, extremely unlikely but possible -- then life gets interesting.

Comment: I'll try my best to answer all of these: I do not know how that part of the wall is framed. The chimney/fireplace is made of brick. Drilling a small pilot hole near the floor resulted in hitting something hard about a 1/2" in. The fireplace and chimney are indeed functional, and there is a natural gas starter line. The house was built in the 30s and I believe the walls are plaster.